# Configure Webpack to resolve relative paths

Tags: webpack, material-design, webpack-dev-server, material-components, material-components-web

I am trying to implement **Material Web Components** into my Web App as per Material Component Web's [Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).

I was able to successfully set up Webpack (V3) to load the SASS for a web component. This was after running into a problem with the include path. I was able to resolve this by adding this line to my `webpack.config.js`.

```
{
    loader: 'sass-loader',
    options: {
        includePaths: ['./node_modules']
    }
}
```

However, I wasn't as successful compiling the JS.

The component in question is Material Web's [Top App Bar](https://material.io/develop/web/components/top-app-bar/).

In my main js file, I have the following:

```
import {MDCTopAppBar} from './../../node_modules/@material/top-app-bar/index.js';
const topAppBarElement = document.querySelector('.mdc-top-app-bar');
const topAppBar = new MDCTopAppBar(topAppBarElement);
```

I had originally put it as:

```
import {MDCTopAppBar} from './node_modules/@material/top-app-bar/index';
```

But Webpack complained that the file could not be found:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './node_modules/@material/top-app-bar/index'.

I tried adding this code to my `webpack.config.js`, based on Webpack's [Module.alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) documentation, to get around that error but to no avail (likely my error in implementation):

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        MDCTopAppBar: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@material/')
    }
}
```

Alas, the code compiles but in Chrome's DevTools I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@material/base/component". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

This error comes from *Top App Bar's* `index.js` file which imports a bunch of other components:

```
import MDCTopAppBarAdapter from './adapter';
import MDCComponent from '@material/base/component';
import {MDCRipple} from '@material/ripple/index';
import {cssClasses, strings} from './constants';
import MDCTopAppBarBaseFoundation from './foundation';
import MDCFixedTopAppBarFoundation from './fixed/foundation';
import MDCShortTopAppBarFoundation from './short/foundation';
import MDCTopAppBarFoundation from './standard/foundation';
```

Here is a picture of what the file structure looks like for the `Top App Bar` component:

```
/node_modules
  /@material
    /base
    /ripple
    /top-app-bar
      -adapter.js
      -constants
      -index.js
/src
  -main.js
```

In `top-app-bar/index.js`, I could manually go through this file (and any subsequent modules I want to include) and rewrite all the paths as relative but that's a terrible approach.

*How can I configure Webpack to resolve these relative paths automatically?*

I tried using [resolve.modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) in various mutations like this but with no success:

```
resolve: {
     modules: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@material'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@material/base/'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@material/base/component'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@material/top-app-bar/'),
        'node_modules'
     ]
 }
```

Here are my project dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material/top-app-bar": "^0.40.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.2.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "extract-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.4",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.14.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.3"
  }
```

I imagine I either have to figure out what I'm doing wrong with configuring webpack, configure a package like `babel-loader` to sort out the paths, or implement a custom solution similar to webpack's [enhanced-resolve](https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve#creating-a-resolver) but only as a last resort.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is pretty much exactly my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52860296/import-mdcripple-into-custom-element-definition-using-a-non-relative-path

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one stuck on what seems like it would be a trivial problem :)

Comment: @JacobPhillips I've found confirmation of the problem as a sidenote in this [quick start guide](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components). A possible solution is using a plugin like [rollup-plugin-includepaths](https://github.com/dot-build/rollup-plugin-includepaths) to enable use of relative paths but haven't road tested this yet.

Comment: thank you so much for pointing me to this repo!

Comment: Basically, what I've found is that relative paths cannot be resolved dynamically (on load), they must be included in a bundling process, for example, using webpack. There is a [Google Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-web/#1) using Material Web Components that you can analyze for their config.

Comment: Yeah that quick start guide you linked to said they use the `polymer-cli` package to serve html, so that's what I did.